# Integrate ElFinder with existing permission system

Tags: php, hook, bind, elfinder

Is there a way to integrate elfinder with my current user permissions system? I would need some kind of hook which would be triggered before e.g. a file gets deleted. There I should be able to abort the delete command and return some kind of response if the logged in user doesn't have enough permissions.

Closest thing I found until now is this: [Connector Configuration options - Bind](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options#bind)

But it doesn't look like I'm able to abort the current action there....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the way you implemented the server-side connector.

For example, I have a custom connector for PHP backend which saves and returns the files / folders based on a database table. This way, I can set the `read` and `write` options for each file / folder (check the [Client-Server API docs](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-Server-API-2.0#information-about-filedirectory)).

To answer your question, you'll need to tweak the server side connector to set the `read` and `write` attributes, like stated in [this wiki page](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Simple-file-permissions-control).